# How to redirect based on a value of an query string

Tags: php, redirect

When redirecting via php with a query string it also appends the target= part which invalidates the url so how can you redirect without the target= part

i have the following code which redirects successfully but with the target= part

```
<?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
    header("Location:". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
?>
```

what i want to happen is for the redirect to work but without the target= part

what actually happens instead is that when the user is accessing http://idk.com/redirect.asp?target=someurl.html the user is redirected to http://idk.com/target=/someurl.html

edit: i also want it to work for both target and TARGET

Comment: yes thats why i asked the question

Comment: I misread. I thought you wanted that, not that you got it.

Answer (score -1):

`header('Location: /' . $_GET['target']);`

It sounds like this is what you're looking for.

Comment: **Warning!** This will redirect anything the user passes in, even to other sites. Never use user data like that without verifying that the value you got is valid. Someone could create a link like: `idk.com/?target=idk.com.example.com/a-phishing-page-for-your-users`, fooling your users to believe the link is legit (since it first goes to your site).

Comment: uhm is there also something for if an value is not present then use another one for example if i use TARGET=some.html instead of target=some.html

Comment: Sure. I'm not certain why you'd want to do it this way, but you could do something like this:

if (isset($_GET['target']) {
    header('Location: /' . $_GET['target']);
else if (isset($_GET['TARGET']) {
    header('Location: /' . $_GET['TARGET']);
} else {
    header('Location: /');
}

Comment: does not work error is
[Fri Dec 02 15:39:11.902957 2022] [php:error] [pid 13304:tid 1880] [client 192.168.50.77:1060] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token "{" in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\isapi\\gooffupd.asp.php on line 2, referer: http://192.168.50.160/Articles/ousupport.htm

Comment: as already stated by the community, this proposed solution is dangerous and you should advice on the risk. You may also add a notice how to control the risk, like  validating the input through a validation middleware to keep track on security.